# Docker-compose example with hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a docker-compose.yml to create containers.

Can you share an example of docker-compose nginx, which has a hostname accessible from host, for example: web.dev?
Will docker automatically do this for me in /etc/hosts file?

So far I got this:

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
  image: nginx
  ports: 8080:80
```

The problem here is that the container is accessible from http://0.0.0.0:8080.
I want it to be accessible from the host by using http://web.dev. How to do so without each developer redefining /etc/hosts entries?

Comment: you might want to use a DNS for that

Comment: i used to achieve this in vagrant using hostmanager plugin - all i had to do is to specify the host name in the Vagrantfile and it would automatically create host name , vbox ip entries in my etc/hosts file upon vagrant up and would perform a cleanup on vagrant destroy. is there a similar support in docker using docker compose ?

Comment: No, there is not. Docker is not a VM, it's a method of running a process with features like namespacing and cgroups. To adjust your DNS to point your browser with that hostname to the IP of your host, you need to do this on DNS.